# SwiftUI - How to make grid items fill available space

Tags: swiftui, layout, grid, aspect-ratio, lazyvgrid

I am trying to **create a 3x4 grid**.  Each grid item should be the same size.  Together the items should **fill the entire view** (excluding top navigation bar).  The grid should be **flexible** so it stretches or shrinks depending on the size of the view.

So far i have managed to achieve the following:
[image: 3x4 grid with square items. Not scaled to fit view.]

This is the code:

```
struct CustomGrid: View {
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                ForEach(0..<12) { _ in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                 }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

This is how i would like the grid to look:
[image: 3x4 grid with each item scaled to fit the view]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SwiftUI.Layout will let you make any layout you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should help you

```
struct CustomGrid: View {

    let numberOfRows: CGFloat = 4

    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
            GeometryReader { geo in
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                    ForEach(0..<12) { _ in
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                            .frame(height: (geo.size.height / numberOfRows).rounded())
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

You can use `GeometryReader` to define the height of the screen.
And then set the frame height for each `RoundedRectangle` by determining the height of each element by dividing the screen height by the number of rows.
We round up the resulting value, as rendering fractional pixels will greatly affect the rendering engine, and you may encounter lags and frame drops.